# Login on Console: You do not have permission to see it

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, ionic3

I created a database in Firebase, all right here.
The issue is that: The gmail account that I used was deleted.
We created it again, the same. But now when I login to: (my-project).firebaseio.com I get the following message:

"The 'project-url' project does not exist or address@domain.com does not have permission to see it."

What can I do? how can I recover access?. We are using G-suite to control google accounts

Regards!

Comment: Contact firebase support.

Comment: Thanks @AndréKool, I have just done it!